# Regular Expression - SubExpressions - IMDB

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to tokenize film titles which I've downloaded from IMDB's text interface.

A simplified version of the RE will demonstrate the problem I'm having.  Here is a sample title:

```
"'Allo 'Allo!" (1982)
"A film in production" (????)
```

I can match it like so:

```
re=/(\".*\")\s(\(.{4}\));
```

Then I can use the subexpression to tokenize the film in javascript it would be like so:

```
titleParts = rawTitle.match(re);
console.log('title %s', titleParts[0]);
```

But then I discovered film titles like so:

```
Unquoted film title  (2012)
```

Because there are no quotes around the title, I can no longer match the elements into a subexpressions:

```
re=/((\"){0,1}.*(\"){0,1})\s(\(.{4}\));
```

Note that I've changed the original RE by specifying that the quotes are optional.  But what happens now is that the entire string matches the first subExpression.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Since the `(nnnn)` part isn't optional, the first subexpression can't match the entire string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is actually available at index `1` not `0`.

```
console.log('title %s', titleParts[1]); // "title Unquoted film title "
```

You should not be capturing quotes and white spaces around your title. This would lead to inconsistent display of titles: sometimes quoted, sometimes not; or, would require string manipulation that is unnecessary and should be avoided.

If your title string would always have the `(year)` part and assuming IMDB would be using single quotes in movie titles (like in your example) your regex can be simplified to

```
"?(.*?)"?\s+\((.{4})\)
```

Here's some JavaScript to print the titles with quotations consistently:

```
var titles = [
    "\"'Allo 'Allo!\" (1982)",
    "\"A film in production\" (????)",
    "Hachi: A Dog's Tale (2009)"
];

var re = /"?(.*?)"?\s+\((.{4})\)/;

for each ( var t in titles ) {
    var titleParts = t.match(re);
    console.log('Title: "%s" ; Year: %s', titleParts[1], titleParts[2]);
}
```

*Output:*

```
Title: "'Allo 'Allo!" ; Year: 1982
Title: "A film in production" ; Year: ????
Title: "Hachi: A Dog's Tale" ; Year: 2009
```

Comment: Thank you Ravi, but it doesn't always have a quote.

Comment: @hba, my third title at titles[2] already covers that case. It works for both quoted and unquoted titles.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this expression `^("?[\w\s!']+"?)\s\((.{4})\)$` in regexpal and it worked for all your cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use regex for a robust tokenizing solution. Tokenizing is hard enough and I assure that you will run into many more edge cases you have yet to encounter.

Use this instead:

https://npmjs.org/package/tokenizer

Comment: I disagree. Regular expressions are perfectly suitable for this. We're not dealing with a complicated grammar here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I personally disagree. Movie titles are intrinsically very messy data, as is nearly all human-generated text. Especially on a large data set like imdb, I feel like relying on regex is only going to lead to more problems down the line.

Comment: @Slater Tyranus Thank you for pointing out this library, I'll look into it.  I hope I can find some good examples :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the greedy quantifier `.*`, which would match always (the empty string too). Either you use something more specific for capturing the title, like prasanth's suggestion `[\w\s!']+` but maybe you need more punctuation characters, or you use the possessive quantifier `.+?` (I prefer `+` over `*` here, because you want something to catch). So your regex would be:

```
re=/(\"?.+?\"?)\s(\(.{4}\));
```